# overwriting hbase cell in a single put call

Tags: java, hbase

I am wondering what will be the behaviour of overwriting cell values in a single put call using Java API. For example

```
HTable table;
....
Put p = new Put("key".getBytes());
p.add("cf".getBytes(), "qualifier".getBytes(), "value1".getBytes());
p.add("cf".getBytes(), "qualifier".getBytes(), "value2".getBytes());`
table.put(p);
```

I want to know what would be the behaviour?

1. Will there be only one version of cell inserted for row "key"? if yes which one?
2. Will there be two versions of the cell inserted for row "key"? if yes what will be the order?

If it is documented somewhere then a link to the documentation will be good to read as well.

Answer (score 0):

I verified using a simple piece of code

```
public class HbaseSample {
  public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    Configuration config = HBaseConfiguration.create();
    HTable table = new HTable(config, "ehsan_test");
    Put p = new Put("key".getBytes());
    p.add("cf1".getBytes(), "qualifier".getBytes(), "value1".getBytes());
    p.add("cf1".getBytes(), "qualifier".getBytes(), "value2".getBytes());
    table.put(p);
  }
}
```

It looks like option (1) in the question is the right behaviour. Further more its "value2" that is stored.
Any documentation reference, would still be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

In short, the first `add` call was overwritten by the second. Instead of docs reference let's walk through the code:

- [add](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.apache.hbase/hbase/0.94.1/org/apache/hadoop/hbase/client/Put.java#139) on an instance of `Put` calls [createPutKeyValue](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.apache.hbase/hbase/0.94.1/org/apache/hadoop/hbase/client/Put.java#175)
- It creates an instance of `KeyValue`, in this case using the same parameters for row key, column family and the qualifier,
- The [familyMap](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.apache.hbase/hbase/0.94.1/org/apache/hadoop/hbase/client/Put.java#141) in a Put is keyed by family name, so the second call to `add` replaces the value of specified in the first.

And so the last one wins ;)